# Want HP Pavilion 10-e010nr to default PXE Legacy boot from wired network

Tags: networking, boot, pxe

Have Pavilion 10-e010nr note-book laptop. InsydeH2O 3.7 BIOS.

I want it to PXE boot from  the network interface,  in legacy mode, by default.  I am the IT department.

Security:
There are no Administrator Password or Power-On Password at the BIOS level.

System Configuration:

Language is English

Virtualization Technology is Enabled

Action Keys Mode is Enabled

Boot Options:

POST hotkey delay is 5 seconds

Internal Network Adapter Boot is Enabled

Network Support Protocol is IPv4 (Legacy)

Legacy Support is Enabled

Secure Boot is Disabled

Platform Key is Entrolled

Pending Action is None.

UEFI Boot Order

Network Adapter

OS boot Manager

USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Disk

USB CD/DVD ROM Drive

Legacy Boot Order

Network Adapter

Notebook Hard Drive

USB Diskektte on Key / USB Hard Sisk

USB CD/DVD ROM Drive

I have put the Network Adapter at the top of the priority list for EFI and Legacy boot.

I have disabled Secure Boot.

I have enabled Legacy Boot.

It always boots from the local HDD, presumably EFI since it was using Secure Boot before I turned that feature off.

I cannot find a way to force it to (PXE) boot the network interface automatically.

I cannot find a way to force it to try Legacy first.

I can force it to PXE-2.1 build 083 by pressing F-12.

We have over 50, other, Windows, computers on this Clonezilla server, they all do this without difficulty.  Many are HP. We also have Lenovo, Acer, and a lot of full size tower boxes, wth ASUS motherboards.

Without my personal intervention (fingers), this Pavilion always boots from the local disk. An earlier 10-e010nr was successfully configured to boot from the network, before I started here.  So I am confident this computer can do it.

Are there hidden controls to deselect EFI boot?

Are there hidden controls to disable the media types available for EFI boot?

Any hints would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you!

Abbott.Bill@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCs usually have a "UEFI" mode a "Legacy" mode and "Both", it seems you have both modes selected then if your NIC is faulty or not well connected is going to be skipped next if the only bootable media is an UEFI disk then you'll get that booted. Check the NIC and related stuff.

Comment: Hi Pat, Thank you, yes, I'd expect to be able to select UEFI or Legacy or Both, but tbe "InsydeH2O" interface Ver 3.7 does not offer that selection on this or other, 'value' range HPs.

We have the previous Pavilion 10 TS, a 215 and a 355. They all have the same InsydeH2O Ver 3.7 interface, and PXE boot to the network. I've duplicated their settings on my new Pavilion 10 and it will not.

The remaining difference is this new Pavilion has the Win8.1 it came with, the others all have our Win10 image from our Clonezilla. So I'm going to coerce it and see what I get.

Comment: To be clear: I am confident in the NIC, becuase I can use F-12, manually, to get it to PXE to the network. What I can't get is that to happen automatically. Back with more when I finish putting my Clonezilla Win10 on it, via F-12...

Comment: I see; definitely a firmware issue from our friends at HP...

Comment: HI Pat. Yep, firmware issue at HP. With Win10 from our Clonezilla server, it DOES got to the network when booted. A human has to boot it, by pressing the power/reset button above the keyboard. But once that button is pressed, it does what I wanted and expected- a PXE boot, which can receive a Clonezilla OS install OR a boot-local-disk, which gets whatever was imaged most recently.